# Systemd/Linux ReadWritePaths not working

Tags: linux, systemd

I am trying to improve security on the flask webserver running as a systemd service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Configuration Server

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/configui
ProtectSystem=full
ProtectHome=yes
CapabilityBoundingSet=CAP_NET_ADMIN CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE 
ReadWritePaths=/var/lib/configui/
NoNewPrivileges=yes
PrivateTmp=yes
PrivateDevices=yes
DevicePolicy=closed
ProtectControlGroups=yes
ProtectKernelModules=yes
ProtectKernelTunables=yes
RestrictAddressFamilies=AF_UNIX AF_INET AF_INET6 AF_NETLINK
RestrictRealtime=yes
RestrictSUIDSGID=yes
MemoryDenyWriteExecute=yes
LockPersonality=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

However I run into a problem when the application tries to write a file `/var/lib/configui/data.json.new` which is a temporary file. After this is done the application overwrites `/var/lib/configui/data.json` with it. Python throws a permission denied error. The contents of said directory:

```
root@XXXXXX:/var/lib/configui# ls -ll
total 16
-rw-r----- 1 userA userA  589 Jul 30  2020 data.json
```

I know that I can get it working by adding CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE but that defeats the purpose of limiting read write operations.

Comment: could you `chown root` the file? or alternatively run the service as `User=userA` and change `CapabilityBoundingSet=`  to `AmbientCapabilities=`?

Comment: ah, please show who owns the containing directory i.e `ls -ld /var/lib/configui`, i think that's more important than the file if you are replacing it using rename()

Comment: I solved the issue by using StateDirectory=configui